# Converting a Source+Binary Docker image into a Binary only docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker for development purposes. At the end of the development, I now have the dependency libraries and also the binaries for my project.

Now I want to deploy this container in production, but I don't want to push a binary with my source code in it (for obvious reasons).

Are there any tools to help me do this in an effective way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use case for multi-stage builds. To take a simplified Java example Dockerfile:

```
# first stage, just run this in dev environments
FROM jdk as build
# install dependencies
COPY src /src
# ... do build

# second stage, for prod use
FROM jre
# install dependencies
COPY --from=build /src/app.jar /app/
CMD java -jar /app/app.jar
```

You can build just the first stage with:

```
docker build --target build -t app:dev .
```

And then run the full build for your production image. The important part is the `COPY --from` line which will copy files from a prior image into the later one. This lets you have the full compile environment in the first stage, and just the runtime environment in the final stage, and copying the compiler output between the two.